# How to link a python data structure into matplotlib? Such as a dict -> bar chart

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, ipython, apl

I have a colleague who showed me his work environment in some other language. He had the ability to create an empty dict-like object and pass a pointer to this object to some other charting library. This charting library would then create a windowed bar chart. Since the dict-like object was empty, the chart displayed nothing.

Now, as he updated his dict-like object by inserting key,value pairs into the object, the chart would magically update, in realtime, with his changes.

It seemed incredibly awesome and since I am huge python fan, I want to show him that "anything he can do, we can do better!" However, I am at a loss as to how to do this -- can you guys help?

*If it matters, his environment was APL-based.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to write a `dict` subclass that has a `__setitem__` method that redraws the chart each time an item is changed. For bonus points, check to make sure the item was actually changed to avoid unnecessary redraws.

```
class Chartdict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            if self[key] != value:
                self[key] = value
                # do whatever you need to do to update the chart here
```

I've not used `matplotlib` so I don't know what you actually need to do to update a chart from a dict -- I've left that to you.

Comment: Ok, but how do I cast a dict to a Chartdict? Is there a way to do it without repopulating an entire Chartdict?

Comment: `mydict = Chartdict(mydict)` will do. Or you can just start it out empty with `mydict = Chartdict()` and add items to it in the usual way.